# Developing a user search page in asp.net MVC 4 using Activedirectory

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory, windows-authentication

I am developing a ASp.net MVC 4 Intranet application.
So when I login I can see my account getting displayed.
Now to authorise the account I have developed a custom authorization provider by following the below link :http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607392/Custom-Role-Providers

now my problem is after the initial authorization I add myself to superadmin role who has acess to Index.cstml where there is a text box and a search button.

basically here on this page I want to **search user from active directory** and display it so that I can assign some roles to the user.
How do I do that?
please provide the code how to connect to Active directory, where to provide the connection string for LDAP and the excat method which will help me in searching the user from active directory and dispaly it on the index view.

Below is what I have tried:
Entities: ADuser->property UserLoginName ,UserDispalyName
Model: has a method that returns the serch user from AD and add it to entity
public class ADUserModel
    {

```
    public List<ADUser> GetUserFromAD(string name) //Get Network Users (AD)
    {
        //ArrayList searchUser = new ArrayList();
        var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        var groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "Domain Users");
        UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(domainContext);
        user.Enabled = true;
        user.Name = name + "*";

        PrincipalSearcher pS = new PrincipalSearcher();
        pS.QueryFilter = user;

        PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = pS.FindAll();
        var list = new List<ADUser>();


        //searchUser.Add(results);
        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            var users = new ADUser();
            users.UserLoginName = item.SamAccountName;
            users.UserDisplayName = item.DisplayName;
            list.Add(users);
            //searchUser.Add(users);
        }

        return list;

    }
}
```

Controller: has an action method that will return the view

public class ManageUsersController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /ManageUsers/

```
    public ActionResult Search(string searchString)
    {
        ADUserModel model = new ADUserModel();
        var list = new List<ADUser>();
        if (searchString != null)
        {
            list = model.GetUserFromAD(searchString);
            return View("Search");
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Search");
        }
    }
}
```

View: Search.cshtml

```
 @model IEnumerable<FMSKendoUI.Entities.ADUser>
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Search";
  }
@Html.BeginForm("Search","ManageUsers",FormMethod.Get)
{
@Html.TextBox("Search") <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}

@if (Model.Count() != 0)
{

    @foreach (FMSKendoUI.Entities.ADUser model in Model)
    {

            @Html.DisplayFor(m => model.UserLoginName)
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => model.UserDisplayName)

    }


}
```

But my problem is:
During my first page load I would need only the textbox and search button.
and on the search button click I need to call the controller search method.

Since during the first time my entity is null it is giving me null exception.
my entity get loaded only after I provide the search string and call the model  method.

I am unable to achieve this. Please help me on this.

Comment: This site is to help people with concrete problems, not to implement full solutions. Please, try something, and then, if you have some trouble, post it and someone will help you!

Comment: I could solve this one also on my own after lots of trails and logics, even after providing the code nobody helped me.

Comment: I'm glad you've learned the basics of ASP.NET MVC. Next time, I'm sure your question will be interesting. This one was a hidden "I have never use MVC and I want to do this. Please, solve my problem for me!". Nex time your question will be something like "I'm tring to do this with MVC, and have tried that, but it's not working. What can I do to solve this problem?". So, I'm sure, next time there will be people that helps you. Seriously! People in SO are really helpful for real problems.

Comment: Ok Thank you very much for ur suggessions